# Representation of the elements of $c_0^\perp$ as integrals over ultrafilters

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ultrafilters, duality

Let 
$$
X=\big\{\varphi\in\ell_\infty^{\,*}(\mathbb N) : \varphi(\{a_n\})=0\,\,\text{whenever $a_n\to 0$}\big\}.
$$
If $\varphi_{\mathscr F}(\{a_n\})$ is the limit of $\{a_n\}$ with respect to the non-principal ultrafilter $\mathscr F\in\beta\mathbb N$, then clearly $\varphi_{\mathscr F}\in X$.

I was wondering whether the elements of $X$ can be represented as
$$
\varphi=\int_{\beta\mathbb N}\varphi_{\mathscr F}\,d\mu(\mathscr F),
$$
where $\mu$ is complex Borel measure on $\beta\mathbb N$ (or perhaps on $\beta\mathbb N\!\setminus\!\mathbb N$).

Is this written somewhere?

Comment: The space $\ell_\infty(N)$ can be identified with $C(\beta N)$, the space of continuous functions on the compact $\beta N$. By the Riesz representation theorem,  $C(\beta N)^*$ can be identified with the space of Borel measures  $M(\beta N)$. Therefore, for every $F\in \ell_\infty(N)^*$ there exists a measure $\mu_F \in M(\beta N)$ so that $F(f)=\int_{ \beta N} f(t) d\mu_F(t)$ for each  $f\in C(\beta N)$.

Comment: @M.González Could you please provide some reference?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expanded version of the previous comment.

In Section 3 (The Stone–Čech compactification of the natural numbers) of the following link [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers) you can find that $\beta\mathbb{N}$, the Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, can be seen as the set of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, that $\mathbb{N}$ is a dense subset of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ (the trivial ultrafilters), and that $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ can be identified in a natural way with $C(\beta\mathbb{N})$.

Therefore, by the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) for $C(K)$ spaces (also called the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem), the dual space of $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ can be identified with $M(\beta\mathbb{N})$, the space of finite Borel measures on $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Now, for every $F\in \ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})^*$ there exists a measure $\mu_F\in M(\beta\mathbb{N})$ so that, given $x=(x_n)\in \ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$, we have $F(x)=\int_{\beta\mathbb{N}} f(t) d\mu_F(t)$, where $f\in (\beta\mathbb{N})$ is determined by $f(n)=x_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$).

The functionals $F\in \ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})^*$ which are zero on the subspace $c_0$ ($F\in X$) can be identified with the measures with support contained in $\mathbb{N}^*=\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, the non-trivial ultrafilters.